# SQLite index performance

Tags: performance, sqlite, indexing

I have a table in the following layout

`email, item_id, json` where

- `email` is a string
- `item_id` is a unix timestamp in ms
- `json` is the item data to be used with the JSON1 extension

and I also have a multi-column index on that table with `email, id`

I perform a lot of queries in the style of `WHERE email = 'asd' AND item_id > ... AND item_id < ...`

I've been dealing with MongoDB for too many years now, so I'm used to not dealing with database normalization, and just went with the easiest SQL table layout.

On a phone, a query for the abovementioned style can take up to a second for a 35000 item query. The index does get used.

Will I get a noticeable performance boost when I normalize the database by creating a new table with `email, email_id` and change the original to `email_id, item_id, json` and start querying via JOINS? In that case `email, email_id` would contain about 2-5 items and `email_id, item_id, json` many thousands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using 3 tests the original, a query using a JOIN and an additional option, using a subquery rather than a join to get the email id based upon the email address and compare this to the email_id. The subquery came out on top, the original fared worst.

#### Results were :-

```
SELECT * FROM original WHERE email = 'email3@ouremail.com' AND item_id > 7800 AND item_id < 2404327029516376406
```

> OK
>   Time: 0.199s

```
SELECT * FROM item WHERE email_id = (SELECT email.email_id FROM email WHERE email.email = 'email3@ouremail.com') AND item_id > 7800 AND item_id < 2404327029516376406
```

> OK
>   Time: 0.082s

```
SELECT * FROM item JOIN email ON item.email_id = email.email_id WHERE email.email = 'email3@ouremail.com' AND item_id > 7800 AND item_id < 2404327029516376406
```

> OK
>   Time: 0.109s

The following was used to create and test :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS original;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS original (email TEXT, item_id INTEGER, json BLOB, PRIMARY KEY(email,item_id));
WITH RECURSIVE cnt(x,y,z) 
AS (
    SELECT 'email'||(1 + ABS(random() / (9223372036854775807 / 5)))||'@ouremail.com',
                ABS(random()),
          randomblob(ABS(random() / (9223372036854775807 / 40) ))
            UNION ALL SELECT 
              'email'||(1 + ABS(random() / (9223372036854775807 / 5)))||'@ouremail.com',
                ABS(random()),
                randomblob(ABS(random() / (9223372036854775807 / 40)))  
            FROM cnt LIMIT 350000
)
INSERT INTO original SELECT * FROM cnt;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS email;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS email (email_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, email TEXT);
INSERT INTO email SELECT DISTINCT null,email FROM original;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS item;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS item (email_id, item_id, json);
INSERT INTO item SELECT 
    (SELECT email_id FROM email WHERE original.email = email.email),
        item_id,
        json FROM original;


SELECT * FROM original WHERE email = 'email3@ouremail.com' AND item_id > 7800 AND item_id < 2404327029516376406;
SELECT * FROM item WHERE email_id = (SELECT email.email_id FROM email WHERE email.email = 'email3@ouremail.com') AND item_id > 7800 AND item_id < 2404327029516376406; 
SELECT * FROM item JOIN email ON item.email_id = email.email_id WHERE email.email = 'email3@ouremail.com' AND item_id > 7800 AND item_id < 2404327029516376406;
```

You could worse then to run the following and look at the output.

```
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM original WHERE email = 'email3@ouremail.com' AND item_id > 7800 AND item_id < 2404327029516376406;
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM item WHERE email_id = (SELECT email.email_id FROM email WHERE email.email = 'email3@ouremail.com') AND item_id > 7800 AND item_id < 2404327029516376406;
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM item JOIN email ON item.email_id = email.email_id WHERE email.email = 'email3@ouremail.com' AND item_id > 7800 AND item_id < 2404327029516376406;
```

Comment: Thanks for showing how to create such a benchmark with SQL only.